# Difference between Expected digest and Actual digest in CXF web service (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, digital-signature

```
16:56:06,477 DEBUG DOMReference:398 - Expected digest: 3BXXHthnTP9kC1YB6FPUrpnO72wNuPmWerwglakCGiY=
16:56:06,477 DEBUG DOMReference:399 - Actual digest: hesLZ/G8ekBPdFNGrxIJmxSYhhMC/BBHD6x/pHqXJt4=
16:56:06,477 DEBUG DOMXMLSignature:276 - Reference[#Body] is valid: false
```

I have a web service done in CXF and I have done a client just by using  javax.xml.crypto
package utilities. On the client side when I check the validity of the signature it says valid. Where I have digest of body section as "3BXXHthnTP9kC1YB6FPUrpnO72wNuPmWerwglakCGiY=".

Then generated SOAP message is being sent and at the web service side it says actual digest is something else but not what I got in client side.

Can anyone shed some light on this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading the SOAP msg from a file. There have been some non-UTF8 chars which got 
included in to digest. However I was canonicalizating before digest which should fix this kind of issues. Code modified to read only UTF-8 data and that fixed the issue.

```
File attachmentFile = new File("soap_sample.xml");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(attachmentFile);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    String inputLine = null;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(inputLine);
    }

    InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(buffer.toString(), "UTF-8");

    SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), is);
```